# Initializing a class in a function vs in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oop, nestjs

So I am working in a project, which uses `Nest.js`

I have a custom package, which exports the configured `redis` object.

What I need to do, is initialize the custom `redis` class in a function, but all cases in our code, show how to do it in a class. Like so:

```
import { RedisService } from 'custom-redis-package';
//...
export class Gateway implements /*...*/ {
  constructor(
    private readonly redisService: RedisService,
  ) {
    //...
  }
  public foo() {
    this.redisService.bar()//... Use the redisService freely here.
  }
}
```

The problem is now I need to initialize this redis package in a function in `main.ts` to use redis as session memory.

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { RedisService } from 'custom-redis-package';
import * as session from 'express-session';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const redis = new RedisService(); // This would work, but it want's the entire config object. So password, user, all the urls and so on, and it seems like a DRY violation
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: redis.getSessionStorage(session),//Unable to, RedisService is not initialized
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

So, how can I initialize `RedisService` without the whole config mess in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is smth like:

`app.get(serviceAsImportedModule)`.

More info here:

https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications#getting-started